# I want to create a column that displays data of two other columns on Oracle Apex 5.

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am working on Oracle Apex 5. 
I want to create a column that displays a column called year, "hyphen", a column called main. 
For example, it would look like this: 17-001.

I already have the other two columns in the table, I just can't seem to create this new column properly.

Comment: Use concat(field 1, '-', field2) in the select clause.

Comment: That seems like it should but it isn't. On side note, I am writing this code under Default in the Page Item Attributes. (Just in case I might be writing this code in the wrong place)

Comment: Are you creating this as a report column? Or as a page item (since you mentioned you're using Default in the Page Item Attributes). If a page item, where are you getting the YEAR and MAIN values from?

Also, if a page item, will this value be display only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form ID that is based on two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984599/form-id-that-is-based-on-two-columns)